# Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

Log:

> E:\Flutter>flutter doctor Checking Dart SDK version... Downloading
> Dart SDK from Flutter engine ead227f a... Unzipping Dart SDK...
> Updating flutter tool... Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool.
> Retrying in five seconds...
>
> Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Error: Unable to 'pub
> upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...
>
> Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Error: Unable to 'pub
> upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...
>
> Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Error: Unable to 'pub
> upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...
>
> Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Error: Unable to 'pub
> upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...
>
> Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ... Error: Unable to 'pub
> upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...

[image]

Comment: Are you in China or behind a firewall? What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: I collected a few things that people reported to fix the issue for them in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15014#issuecomment-374501940

Comment: It might be possible that you don't have enough free disk space. That's what caused my problems. First cleared up space. Then had to overwrite the flutter SDK folder due to corruption. Then things started working.

Answer (score 41):

First Make sure you have a working internet connection and if this issue still exists, then this error occurs probably because the dart SDK may have not been properly downloaded.
The simplest solution is to delete the `cache` folder located in
`flutter/bin`(location where flutter is installed) and then Run `flutter doctor` (This will redownload the dark SDK)

Comment: I have done that but get exactly the same problem as in the original question, do you know any other potential solutions?

Comment: Then I would recommend you to reinstall flutter SDK ,before that I would recommend other peoples answer on this question.

Answer (score 17):

I fix that by:

1. `Ctrl+C` to stop infinite error loop.
2. Kill the Dart process in Windows Task Manager.
3. Delete the `cache` folder located in `flutter/bin` directory.
4. Run in command line `flutter pub cache repair`.

After that I run `flutter doctor` and get predictable results:

```
e:\tools>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    6.1.7601], locale ru-RU)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 14):

I found my antivirus blocks `pub upgrade`,I had same issue while hitting `flutter doctor`, I turned off my antivirus and tried to run "flutter doctor" again, and worked well!

Answer (score 6):

windows:
simplest and easiest way is download the latest version flutter sdk. replace manually current folder by pasting downloaded flutter folder instead of the current folder
in c drive. always choose replace and paste.

after finishing that check with flutter doctor. my issue solved

Answer (score 5):

Solved this issue when Run the CMD as administrative.

Answer (score 3):

This issue will come in protected network as well as due to anti-virus. Even I was facing the same. I downloaded latest stable version manually from the following link, which doesn't required any update process and it works for now..

[Download Link For Flutter in Zip format](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Answer (score 3):

I updated the flutter SDK via `git pull`, then the `flutter doctor` command works.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete cache directory in flutter/bin
2. Then run flutter doctor

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the cache folder in flutter/bin and run `flutter doctor` again!!

Answer (score 1):

Just Deactivate your antivirus and run it again. It would work fine. I had the same issue before.

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated my antivirus for some time and executed flutter doctor command once again in cmd and got fruitful results after hours of patience.
One more thing to note, you should ensure that path of dart-sdk folder should be added to the path in user variables.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not being able to "unzip" the downloaded Dart file because it misses 7-zip uncompressor.
I installed it and it worked! It will deal with .7z files.
I hope it works for other people too!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was solved.

Steps:

Download Dart and Filters SDK then Decompress these files and move them to this directory.

`C: \`
Define the variables in path:

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faces this problem on macOS with AdGuard installed. Try this:

Go `AdGuard Preferences -> Network -> Automatically filter applications -> Select Mode...` and change mode to `Automatic Proxy.`

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users. In my case just worked after doing it with privileges:

```
sudo -s
dart pub cache repair
```

And them again:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/miguelgamboa/.pub-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you downloaded the windows powershell i use windows 8 it wasn't installed by default , when i downloaded it  it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your flutter bin path in environment variable(User Variables). If not go to Under User variables check if there is an entry called Path:in that add this flutter/bin path.

Answer (score 0):

Strangly when I **kill the dart process in Windows Task Manager** it is working. But sometimes even when dart process is running update working.

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off the Android Emulator. It was running for me...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and was not able to get rid of it. So I deleted the flutter and instead of cloning it I downloaded the zip from the flutter website and extracted it. Now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Manually downloading the SDK from flutter website fixed the issue.

Still dont know why this problem occured tho.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error resolve after adding below folder into exclude option in anti virus

Flutter SDK location
`D:\Android\flutter_windows\flutter\*.`

Flutter Local Pub folder
`C:\Users\hitesh\AppData\Local\Pub`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Avast` (or possibly some other anti virus too) on Mac and have recently updated the OS to Big Sur then follow the below steps to fix this issue

1. Open Avast and in the Web Shield area disable the "`Scan secure connection`".
2. Run `flutter config --no-analytics` and then run `pub upgrade`.

This should probably fix the issue.

You can also refer to below threads in Github for more details about the cause

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40515

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68999

Answer (score 0):

You get the error --
"Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left)" even if you are in one of the flutter directories from Windows explorer. Close the window and try running Flutter doctor. This will resolve.

Comment: Format the code/error messages in the answer body properly.

Answer (score 0):

Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

Comment: This seems more like a new question than an answer, you may want to create a new question or search for similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Tried switch to Dev channel and got stuck with "Unable to pub upgrade". Did everything and nothing worked.

This is what I did:

- Renamed the Flutter SDK folder
- Download the latest Flutter SDK
- Extract to the same location of previous renamed SDK
- Flutter channel Dev
- Flutter upgrade

And everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

##### Source of Problem

It might be possible that you don't have enough free disk space. That's what caused my problems to begin with.

##### Solution

In my case,

- First I had to clean up space to remove any unused files.
- Then I had to overwrite the flutter SDK folder due to corruption. The SDK can be found [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my MacBook M1. I tried deleting and running `flutter pub cache repair` But It didn't work for me.

Then I ran the command `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` and accepted the software licences & agreement (After installing XCode). Now the command `flutter` works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all of the above without success. The search order in the PATH system variable turned out to be the problem:

it was:

```
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin;
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\flutter;
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\flutter.bat;
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\dart.exe;
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\dart;
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\dart.bat;
```

changed it to:

```
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\flutter
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\dart
    G:\My Drive\Compilers\flutter\bin\dart.bat
```

that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

**Mac auto iCloud upload might be causing the error**

If you are using Mac and if your Desktop files are being uploaded to iCloud automatically, sometimes iCloud uploads the "bin" file or the "cache" file inside the flutter file. I've just downloaded the file onto desktop (right click the file -> "Download Now") and it downloaded the file, it ran as usual. (Automatic upload can be turned off from system preferences if youn are getting this error frequently like I was).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i was using ubuntu, and after reading the above comments, i have come to a resolution that the above error comes as a result of permissions being blocked, accessing cmd with admin access levels solves the problem, e.g on linux run `sudo flutter doctor` and the problem will be solved.
This error occured to me when i tried upgrading my flutter so it needed admin rights to be upgraded nothing much

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, with the following steps I solved them:

```
sudo snap remove flutter --purge
sudo snap install flutter
sudo flutter upgrade
```

Comment: error: This revision of snap "flutter" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform
       arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
       which may put your system at risk.

Answer (score 0):

I had removed access to the certificates while setting up a proxy with Postman:

[image]

run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and enter space to select again (star)