# Facing issue building flutter tool... while updating flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am just to trying updating my flutter using ***flutter upgrade*** command.But while updating it stuck at
***building flutter tool...*** . I don't know why. After waiting 4-5 minutes i close my terminal and tried to run again  ***flutter upgrade*** but no use. If anybody faced this issue before please help.

Comment: are there any `dart` processes running while showing *"building flutter tool..."*? if so, be patient and let it finish...

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497109/error-unable-to-pub-upgrade-flutter-tool-retrying-in-five-seconds

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old question but for anyone coming here lately let me try to answer it.

Since I faced this issue multiple times I think it will be helpful to share how I solved it. I found that being stuck at "building flutter tool..." happens usually because of these reasons:

1. Make sure you have a working internet connection: check issues like [this one on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250785/7368896)
2. If there is a dart process running while showing the "building flutter tool..." message, be pateint and let it finish as @pskink commented.
3. If there are multiple dart processes running then it maybe waiting for another command to release so stop them or try running `killall dart` on terminal and rerunning `flutter doctor`
4. Delete the cache folder located in flutter/bin directory.(I haven't done this but seems to work for some)

I don't necessarily think this will solve all similar issues but it was how I solved them many times. But I think a detailed log would have been better from flutter. Also checkout this [issue on github.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54943).