# Cannot open file, path = './pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Tags: flutter

After upgrading Flutter to the latest version I am unable to run any flutter command. It is showing the following error:

```
Building flutter tool...                                          
Cannot open file, path = './pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497109/error-unable-to-pub-upgrade-flutter-tool-retrying-in-five-seconds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed this by running `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/flutter`

Comment: Just running `sudo chown -R $USER /opt/flutter`was enough for me. Having two would mean you have a group named the same as your current user.

Comment: @joshpetit that was the case for me. glad you fixed it!

Comment: In my case running sudo chown -R $USER /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter did the trick (/opt/flutter/ was not found). So for Homebrew users this could be the solution.

Comment: for me it is giving illegal group name

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to fix it: Add your user to `flutterusers` group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G flutterusers $(whoami)
```

**NOTE**: remember to restart or logout/login in order for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score -1):

On your android studio or VScode delete `pubspec.lock` and run

```
sudo chown -R $USER:root
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using linux OS just use the command chmod 777 -R in the project folder, this error is caused by lack of permissions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).