# Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error when I run `flutter doctor`

```
Building flutter tool...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.0-4.0.dev.flutter-06cb010247.

Because flutter_tools depends on collection >=1.15.0-nnbd <1.15.0-nullsafety.2 which requires SDK version >=2.9.0-18.0 <=2.9.10, version
  solving failed.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.0-4.0.dev.flutter-06cb010247.
```

I have tried this suggested solution but I get exactly the same error as above:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58283307/12671198

Do I need to downgrade my Dart SDK? And if so how is this done?

Comment: can you please add your `pubspec.yaml` to the original post, It looks like your dart SDK version is incompatible with `collection`. 

so the SO link above is inappropriate to your issue.

Comment: @MaheshJamdade I have made a lot of changes since I posted this. I believe my solution was to uninstall and reinstall Flutter

Answer (score 0):

If you've rooted out network issues as the cause of the problem, it's likely that dart version dependencies is the root of the issue as stated in the error:

```
Because flutter_tools depends on collection >=1.15.0-nnbd <1.15.0-nullsafety.2 which requires SDK version >=2.9.0-18.0 <=2.9.10, version
  solving failed.
```

Checking a similar [issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62146), switching to a different `flutter` branch fixed the issue.