# "Building flutter tool..." stuck when I run "flutter doctor"

Tags: flutter, dart

```
% flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  200M  100  200M    0     0  4039k      0  0:00:50  0:00:50 --:--:--  829k
Building flutter tool...
// HANGS HERE
```

I was waiting for 30minutes. But it was no response.

At first, I upgraded flutter. and met "Building flutter tool..." stuck. So I reinstalled flutter SDK. and ran "flutter doctor" after installing flutter SDK. But I met "Building flutter tool..." stuck too.

When I push Ctrl-C to stop command, it shows

```
Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds ... (9 tries left)
```

I'm in Korea. It is not a country issue. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe restarting your machine will solve it.

Comment: @HamdamMuqimov I restarted my machine several times. but it is not solved.

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497109/error-unable-to-pub-upgrade-flutter-tool-retrying-in-five-seconds

Comment: I used VPN while updating this and it gets downloaded fine. Otherwise, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I just RUN on the flutter folder and solved.

- git clean -xfd
- git stash save --keep-index
- git stash drop
- git pull
- flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VPN and run `flutter upgrade` again. Make sure to have a bit patience between 5 - 10 mins.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a different network and retrying. It saved me :D