# Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying for `flutter doctor` and the following error was shown

```
Running pub upgrade...
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

Waiting for 2 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

[image]

the above initializing was shown for 4 hours. What may be the issue? Can anyone please help with this

Comment: which OS you used Mac or Windows?

Comment: windows 10. Can you please help me with this

Comment: You can try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497109/error-unable-to-pub-upgrade-flutter-tool-retrying-in-five-seconds

Comment: download latest version from flutter.dev and extract it somewhere and and use that path in your project and and  do it globaly by updating new path in environment variable setting.also make sure you have stable connection when upgrading or updating packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed that by:

1. Ctrl+C to stop infinite error loop.
2. Kill the Dart process in Windows Task Manager.
3. Delete the cache folder located in `flutter/bin` directory.
4. Run in command line `flutter pub cache repair`.
5. Run `flutter doctor`

Comment: there is no Dart process in task manager

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps hope its help to you:

1. Go to your flutter directory
2. Delete **cache** folder inside `flutter/bin` directory
3. Then try to run  **`flutter doctor`**

Comment: No use. anyways thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

**First** Make sure you have a working internet connection and if this issue still exists then, this error may be because the dart SDK may have not been properly downloaded. The simplest solution is to delete the cache folder located in the flutter/bin(the location where the flutter is installed) and then Run the flutter doctor.

**Also **try turning off your 'Antivirus' and try 'flutter doctor'

Answer (score 0):

The flutter tool is fundamentally broken. It cannot reliably do an upgrade.
It is a mix of Bash, BAT & Powershell scripts, which are very cryptic and fragile.
They can fail due to various reasons, including permissions, bad internet connection, disk space etc. The scripts fail to provide meaningful error messages. What on earth is **The system cannot find the path specified.**?
What path? Then they run an endless loop trying to somehow magically 'fix'
the issue.

To avoid these issues, download the full Flutter SDK to a chosen directory, unzip it, and update the PATH accordingly yourself. The Flutter SDK contains also the Dart SDK.

Also one gotcha. If you have multiple Flutter installations, be sure to run the
flutter from outside the bin directory like so: `bin\flutter doctor`. You may accidentally run flutter from a different location.