# Building flutter tool... Got TLS error trying to find package args at https://pub.dev

Tags: flutter, dart

When running `flutter doctor` or `flutter upgrade`

Console first shows for a few minutes:

`Building flutter tool...`

Then I receive this:

> Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
> Got TLS error trying to find package args at https://pub.dev.

I noticed that I even wasn't able to access https://pub.dev in the browser due to SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. However I fixed that but the flutter problem still persists.

I have tried reinstalling flutter completely, removing all caches, manually download and unzip and all other answers from this thread [Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497109/error-unable-to-pub-upgrade-flutter-tool-retrying-in-five-seconds?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)
but with no success.

Anyone has a recommendation on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it myself, still a mystery though why that worked.

`git checkout origin/dev`

`git status` gave me a detached HEAD warning.

`git checkout origin/master && git fetch && git pull`

`flutter doctor` was now working.

However I still receive under `Network resources`:

> A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://pub.dev/": Handshake error in
> client
> You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or
> you may have malware installed on your computer.

Comment: Finally figured out the issue (thanks to chatgpt I guess). I had a dnsmasq service running that redirected all *.dev requests to localhost. After removing this in the dnsmasq config `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf ` , flutter tool was building again. Hope it helps someone stumbling across this.